# Previous and next buttons not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain why this works in Firefox and not in Chrome?
It's about the green buttons that appear in the left and right bottom corners. Left should go to 2008 and right should go to 2010. This works in Firefox but not in Chrome. In Chrome left goes to 2007 and right to 2015.

Based on the current URL and a list of div's, the url's of the buttons change.

http://herenloop.nl/2009

Edit:

In this example the url is http://herenloop.nl/2009 but can also be /2001 or /2016.

With this url, my hidden div list of url is (observe that /2009 is not present in the list):

```
<div id="WalkingYears" style="position: absolute; left: -9999;">
<div id="Walk2016" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2016" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=25329364189_99168f141a_o.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2016"></div>
<div id="Walk2015" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2015" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f2015.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2015"></div>
<div id="Walk2014" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2014" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f14.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2014"></div>
<div id="Walk2013" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2013" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f13.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2013"></div>
<div id="Walk2012" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2012" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f12.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2012"></div>
<div id="Walk2011" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2011" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f11.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2011"></div>
<div id="Walk2010" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2010" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f10.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2010"></div>
<div id="Walk2008" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2008" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f08.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2008"></div>
<div id="Walk2007" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2007" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f07.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2007"></div>
<div id="Walk2006" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2006" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f06.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2006"></div>
<div id="Walk2005" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2005" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f05.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2005"></div>
<div id="Walk2004" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2004" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f04.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2004"></div>
<div id="Walk2003" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2003" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f03.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2003"></div>
<div id="Walk2002" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2002" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f02.JPG&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2002"></div>
<div id="Walk2001" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2001" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2fcourtstgeorge_h.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2001"></div>
<div id="Walk2000" data-target="http://herenloop.nl/2000" data-img="/DesktopModules/DnnForge - NewsArticles/ImageHandler.ashx?Width=100&amp;Height=100&amp;HomeDirectory=%2fPortals%2f8%2f&amp;FileName=Afbeeldingen%2fAlbumomslagen%2f00.jpg&amp;PortalID=8&amp;q=1&amp;s=1" data-title="Herenloop2000"></div>
</div>
```

This is the script I use for this:

```
var xlocation = window.location.href.match(/(\/[a-zA-Z]+\/)|(\d+)/);
$el = $('#WalkingYears div[id^=Walk]'),
$elSorted = $el.slice().sort(sorter)
prev = jQuery.grep($elSorted,function(el,i){
    return $(el).attr('data-title').replace(/^\D+/g, '')*1<xlocation[0]*1
})
next = jQuery.grep($elSorted,function(el,i){
    return $(el).attr('data-title').replace(/^\D+/g, '')*1>xlocation[0]*1
})
var sorter = function(a,b){
a = $(a).attr('data-title').replace(/^\D+/g, '')*1,
b = $(b).attr('data-title').replace(/^\D+/g, '')*1
return b-a
}

$('#balk-prev-btn').prop('href',$(prev).first().attr('data-target'));
$('#balk-prev-btn').prop('title',$(prev).first().attr('data-title'));
$('#balk-prev-btn img').prop('src',$(prev).first().attr('data-img'));
$('#balk-prev-btn img').prop('alt',$(prev).first().attr('data-title'));
$('#balk-next-btn').prop('href',$(next).last().attr('data-target'));
$('#balk-next-btn').prop('title',$(next).last().attr('data-title'));
$('#balk-next-btn img').prop('src',$(next).last().attr('data-img'));
$('#balk-next-btn img').prop('alt',$(next).last().attr('data-title'));

function setNextPrev() {
    var dataPrevLink = $('#balk-prev-btn').attr('href');
    var dataNextLink = $('#balk-next-btn').attr('href');
    if (dataPrevLink != '') {
        $('#dock .prev-btn').stop().delay(2000).animate({
            'margin-left': 0
        }, {duration: 700, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
    } else {
        $('#dock .prev-btn').stop().delay(2000).animate({
            'margin-left': -100
        }, {duration: 700, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
    }
    if (dataNextLink != '') {
        $('#dock .next-btn').stop().delay(2000).animate({
            'margin-right': 0
        }, {duration: 700, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
    } else {
        $('#dock .next-btn').stop().delay(2000).animate({
            'margin-right': -100
        }, {duration: 700, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
    }
}
setNextPrev();
```

The script takes the current url, looks at the list of other url's in the hidden div list, sorts them and picks a prev an next url, some other data is attached to the buttons like title and image.

It works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Thank you

Comment: Reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle. Most folks on SO won't click on scary off-site links

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Some of us won't (can't) go to a JSFiddle. Better to include the content *in the question itself* so that others can reproduce the issue without leaving SO.

Comment: ok, @j08691, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact it didn't work correct in Chrome had to do with the order of the script. I placed the sorter function like below and it worked.

```
var sorter = function(a,b){
var a = $(a).attr('data-title').replace(/^\D+/g, '')*1,
b = $(b).attr('data-title').replace(/^\D+/g, '')*1
return b-a
}
$el = $('#WalkingYears div[id^=Walk]');
$elSorted = $el.slice().sort(sorter);
prev = jQuery.grep($elSorted,function(el,i){
return $(el).attr('data-title').replace(/^\D+/g, '')*1<xlocation[0]*1
})
next = jQuery.grep($elSorted,function(el,i){
return $(el).attr('data-title').replace(/^\D+/g, '')*1>xlocation[0]*1
})
```